# MySQL Table Performance

Tags: mysql, performance, database-design

I've a table in MySQL which has more than 50 Million rows. Bellow is the table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `links` (                                          
      `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,                      
      `loc` text NOT NULL,                                          
      `lastmod` datetime NOT NULL,                                  
      `changefreq` varchar(15) NOT NULL,                            
      `priority` float NOT NULL,                                    
      `isdownloaded` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,                           
      `mainrepoid` bigint(20) NOT NULL,                             
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`),                                           
      FULLTEXT KEY `locfulltext` (`loc`)                            
    ) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=11426345 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

FullText is enabled on field **loc**. I need to fetch all the rows containing both **name** and **details** words. The following query didn't return the expected results:

```
SELECT *
FROM links
WHERE 
MATCH (
   loc
)
AGAINST (
   'name +details' IN BOOLEAN MODE
)
```

so I am forced to use the following query:

```
SELECT id, loc
FROM links
WHERE 
loc like '%name%' and
loc like '%details%'
```

Is there any better alternative?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which version of mySql do you use. But the following query that you give works very well in my server.

```
SELECT *
FROM links
WHERE 
MATCH (
   loc
)
AGAINST (
   'name +details' IN BOOLEAN MODE
)
```

If you fetch a problem with this query till now then just try with add a plus(+) sign before `name` . Just like :

```
SELECT *
FROM links
WHERE 
MATCH (
   loc
)
AGAINST (
   '+name +details' IN BOOLEAN MODE
)
```

For further more information see the following link:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-boolean.html